# How to install all SDL libraries in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, sdl

```
dpkg -l | grep sdl
```

This command gives me the following detail:

```
ii  libsdl1.2debian:i386                                        1.2.15-8ubuntu1.1                                   i386         Simple DirectMedia Layer
```

I don't know whether SDL 1.2 is being installed on my system or not?
Also, do I need to install sdl image, mixer, ttf etc etc? How to install them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can search for all available instances of `libsld1.2` with something like the following:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ apt-cache search ^libsdl | grep 1.2
libsdl1.2-dbg - Simple DirectMedia Layer debug files
libsdl1.2-dev - Simple DirectMedia Layer development files
libsdl1.2debian - Simple DirectMedia Layer
libsdl-image1.2-dbg - Image loading library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 1.2, debugging
libsdl-mixer1.2-dbg - Mixer library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 1.2, debugging
libsdl-net1.2-dbg - Network library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 1.2, debugging
libsdl-gfx1.2-4 - drawing and graphical effects extension for SDL
libsdl-gfx1.2-dev - development files for SDL_gfx
libsdl-gfx1.2-doc - documentation files for SDL_gfx
libsdl-image1.2 - Image loading library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 1.2, libraries
libsdl-image1.2-dev - Image loading library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 1.2, development files
libsdl-mixer1.2 - Mixer library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 1.2, libraries
libsdl-mixer1.2-dev - Mixer library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 1.2, development files
libsdl-net1.2 - Network library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 1.2, libraries
libsdl-net1.2-dev - Network library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 1.2, development files
libsdl-sound1.2 - Sound library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 1.2, libraries
libsdl-sound1.2-dev - Sound library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 1.2, development files
libsdl-ttf2.0-0 - TrueType Font library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 1.2, libraries
libsdl-ttf2.0-dev - TrueType Font library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 1.2, development files
andrew@corinth:~$
```

and then simply install all of the resulting files with something like the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian libsdl-gfx1.2-5 \
libsdl-gfx1.2-dev libsdl-gfx1.2-doc libsdl-image1.2 \
libsdl-image1.2-dbg libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2 \
libsdl-mixer1.2-dbg libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-net1.2 \
libsdl-net1.2-dbg libsdl-net1.2-dev libsdl-sound1.2 \
libsdl-sound1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libsdl-ttf2.0-dev
```

You can easily leave some out such as the `.dbg` files which are simply debugging extras and you will not need the `-dev` files unless you are compiling. Some will also be dependencies of the others as well and will be automagically installed with installation of one of these files...

Comment: oh so : `sudo apt install libsdl1.2debian libsdl-gfx1.2-5 libsdl-gfx1.2-dev libsdl-gfx1.2-doc libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dbg libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2 libsdl-mixer1.2-dbg libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-net1.2 libsdl-net1.2-dbg libsdl-net1.2-dev libsdl-sound1.2 libsdl-sound1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libsdl-ttf2.0-dev` ok thanks!

Comment: the shorter answer is better

Answer (score 13):

For installing it:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-2.0
```

and for installing everything necessary to build programs that use SDL:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
```

Comment: How do I install dbg files? Mine can't locate dbg packages. And when `apt-cache search libsdl | grep dbg`, nothing appears!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dbg
```

Or download the SDL source code to compile and install:

[Download SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php)

```
tar xvf SDL-1.2.tar.gz
cd SDL-1.2
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Will it install sdl image, mixer, ttf etc also?

Comment: @dlpsankhla I think not.

Answer (score 0):

If Shahin Bakhshaei's answer (datetime stamp: 2017-04-28T08:43) did NOT yet also solve the problem in your case, please verify using these Terminal Commands:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install libsdl2-dev
```

**Reminder:** We use `libsdl2-dev` when building software applications that use SDL.
This is instead of only executing application programs.

Thank you.